# Hibernate criteria filter by foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables: authors and books. Authors has two colums: int id, varchar authorName. Books has three colums: int id, varchar bookName, int authorId.

Now considering that I take the authorName as an input String filtering criteria how can I make hibernate only return the books by that certain author?

Comment: You mention sorting. Sorting means putting a number of items in a particular order. Do you actually want to sort anything here, or do you just want to filter by the name?

Comment: @TomAnderson I'm sorry, I meant filtering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria( Book.class );
criteria.createCriteria( "author", "a");
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "a.authorName", "YOUR_INPUT"));
criteria.list();
```